# Posting to my site, the page reloads and shows Raw HTML (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my website, when I post a comment, the comment is saved to the database and then the page reloads to show raw HTML rather than the rendered page.  There's no errors, Global.asax isn't called.  When I manually refresh the page, the page is rendered properly.  Any idea where to start why the refresh doesn't work?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string txtCode, string txtName, string txtMessage, string txtEmail)
    {
        List<string> sRules = new List<string>();
```

and at the end

```
        oPackage = ProcessPage();

        if (txtMessage + "" != "" && sRules.Count == 0)
        {
            oPackage.DisplayCommentsSuccess = true;
            Misc.InsertComment(Misc.GetConn(), "EXAMPLE.COM", Request.UserHostAddress, txtMessage, sCat, sPage, txtName, txtEmail, Request.
        else
        {
            oPackage.DisplayCommentsSuccess = false;
        }


        oPackage.Messages = sRules;

        return View(oPackage);
    }
```

ProcessPage rebuilds the page.

Comment: Please show the code in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when posting to the database, the response you get back has:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

in the headers.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I checked the response and now its coming back as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Incidentally, it works on the "production" server but not in developement.

Comment: I've taken what you said and forced it to return the correct Content-Type but don't understand why its not doing it automatically...  It used....  Using code :- Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

Comment: When you refresh the page, you are surely hitting this index action in your controller. This action returns a call to the View method which sets content-type to text/html. Are you sure you are hitting this same index function when you post your comment ? Please include the code you use to POST

Comment: I call ProcessPage which is called by both the Index and the Post function to create the Model that gets past to the View.

Comment: There must be some other part of the code executed by your POST that overrides text/html to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Some logic is doing that for you in an un-realized manner. It would be helpful if you can post the entire POST logic and anything happening around it. If the exact same code returns text/html in production, it is probably some ASP MVC setting that distinguishes behaviour in debug/release modes. Try running locally in Release mode instead of Debug and let me know if you see the same problem.